# When might f != f be true?

Tags: go, syntax

Can anyone elaborate on the subject of `syscalls/js`, why in line 57 there is a statement

```
if f != f { ... }
```

(`f` is of type `float64`).

How is it possible? When can a statement like `i != i` be `true` in `go`?

Comment: Also, edit the title. It isn't reference but value, `go != python => true`

Comment: @LaevusDexter that's completely untrue.

Comment: @hobbs don't hurt my feelings, explain what statement

Comment: "how is it possible when can a statement like i != i can be true in go?" As in almost every other language.

Comment: @LaevusDexter equality on floats is always, and very simply, defined. The idea that it isn't is a common myth spread by those who don't know better. The fault isn't in equality, it's in assuming that two computations that "should" produce equal values *do* produce identical values.

Comment: @hobbs I got it, thanx. I gotta learn english to read between the lines, feel free to yell at me being dumb. Just woke up and then I was already sleeping. But title is wrong, isn't it?

Answer (score 8):

For example if `f` is of type `float64`, and its value is a specific value representing "not a number", which you can get from [`math.NaN()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#NaN). `NaN`–by definition–does not equal to any other `float64` value, including `NaN` itself. The `float64` type uses the [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard which says only `NaN` satisfies the `f != f` unequality.

```
var f float64 = math.NaN()
fmt.Println(f != f)
```

This prints `true`, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KguOuIn0_ug).

For reasoning, see [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)